# Isn't this question not a question, or: Have I lost my mind?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Several days ago I voted to close [The implications of tuning a 12-string guitar in fifths](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85207/the-implications-of-tuning-a-12-string-guitar-in-fifths). If I recall correctly, my close reason was "primarily opinion-based." I didn't see any other votes in support of that closure, and now my vote has expired.

The question does not seem to be a question at all, but a call to discussion:

> I would like to take the chance to discuss the theoretical
>   implications of my alternate tuning for a 12-string guitar. You can
>   find the original question here. So for reference I was talking about
>   the following.

A link and a quote from the original question are included, and that is the entire content of the post. This seems to me like an open-ended request for discussion, and I thought that this sort of thing was plainly off-topic here. Even if this were interpreted as "what are the theoretical implications of tuning a 12-string guitar in fifths," that question would seem too broad and open-ended anyway.

Am I in error, or has this post just fallen through the cracks?

Comment: VTCed as duplicate - the question says right in it that it's a duplicate. Not sure why no one else is seeing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your analysis is correct. But I confess, I still upvoted and starred the question. I think the answers are good enough to *save* the question, even though you're totally right that it's purely subjective and non-constructive.

Comment: All right then; I give up